# How to remove narrow 'notches' in polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, simplify

I am currently working on a project where i am doing a union on several feature classes. The union normally creates several polygons which share edges/borders. however after running dissolve on the union output, i have noticed it also generates these small "alleys" or notches into the polygons:

[image]
(zoomed in)

[image]
(zoomed out)

I was wondering if there is a way to remove these narrow notches in the dissolved feature?

So far i have tried [Simplify Building (ArcGIS Pro)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/simplify-building.htm) with a simplification tolerance of 100 and 1000 meters and a minimum area of 0. This didnt resolve the issue. I would like to avoid doing this manually in an editing session, as there are many of these.

Comment: Try tool Integrate. It will modify your data so backup before you try it.